# Adding Focus on SuggestBox?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, textbox, focus

Hi I want to focus on the SuggestBox as page loads.
I could not find any EventListener for this purpose so I am guessing that I have to
define my own handler to do that (maybe do something with native textbox.focus?)

What is the GWT way to set focus on the text boxes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add textBox.setFocus(true).